# Возможен ли видео файл с переменным количеством кадров?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg

Есть несколько видео файлов, каждый из которых имеет разное количество кадров в секунду (1.mpg, 2.mpg, 3.mpg etc).

Склеиваю в один (result.mpg) с помощью FFMPEG. На выходе получается файл с постоянным количеством кадров (которое было в первом видео файле).

Можно ли склеить их так, чтобы количество кадров в каждой части осталось прежним?
Если да, то как указать это в FFMPEG при склеивании.
Параметры указываю такие:

```
C:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -vsync 0 -i concat:"1.mpg|2.mpg|3.mpg" -c copy result.mpg
```

Comment: попробовал, все по прежнему делает одинаковую частоту кадров